# I cannot set field value (NetSuite)

Tags: javascript, netsuite

Good day.

Hope you can assist. I am trying to set field value in specific field but i can't do that.

The following code is within a 'aftersubmit' operation. Can you spot what I have done wrong?

```
function AFTER SUBMIT(type, form, request){
        var field3 = nlapiGetField('custrecord_dec_suma_valor');
        nlapiSetFieldValue('field3',"Text")
        };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your function declaration. Watch out the space in `AFTER SUBMIT`, you cannot have that. You can try changing it to `AFTER_SUBMIT`. Also, it's not clear what your problem is looking at this function. Can you put a bit exhaustive code so that it's easy to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things incorrect here.

1. As was mentioned in a comment, you cannot have whitespace in your function name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables#An_aside_on_variable_naming_rules
2. You are not using `nlapiSetFieldValue()` correctly; the first parameter is the field ID, not the name of a variable which references the field. It should be `nlapiSetFieldValue("custrecord_dec_suma_valor", "Text");`
3. You cannot set fields during `afterSubmit` this way. The record has already been submitted and stored in the database (hence the name *after submit*). In order to change fields, you will need to load the record, set the field, and save it, or use `nlapiSubmitFields` instead.

I have a whole bunch of videos on my YouTube channel that should help you get started in your SuiteScript journey: https://www.youtube.com/c/StoicSoftware/. Of particular interest to this question will be the [User Event playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLG2tK6Va2WUCseA3viGC2oYPkyA45wfA-) and [Working with Records](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2glMd0y47M).

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work in Suitescript 1.0

```
function AFTER_SUBMIT(type, form, request){
  nlapiSetFieldValue(fldnam, value, firefieldchanged, synchronous);
};
```

Where fldnam = the field id between single or double quotes.
value = the value you want to set.
firefieldchanged is optional, defaults to true. If true, then the fieldchange script for that field is executed.
synchronous is optional, defaults to false. If true, this API executes synchronously.